# Java Graphics2D to erase to a alpha background

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics2d, java-2d, erase

I'm making an application that has a drawing board where you draw with your mouse, it draws ontop of an Label in a BUfferedImage. What I'm trying to implement right now is an eraser, the problem is I cannot find anywhere help to make an eraser to clearRect() to an alpha background. (I cannot have a defined color background since the user can change the background to any image he wants). To sum up:

- How can you erase/overwrite Graphics2D pixels with alpha pixels? The way i found was with clearRect but you need to specify a background color.

The following is my DrawBoard class which constains everything to draw.

```
public class DrawBoard extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{


public JLabel status;
private JLabel imgLabel; // this is where the drawing happens
public Point pstart, pfinish;
private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
private List<BufferedImage> lines = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();

private static final int BI_WIDTH = 1024;
private static final int BI_HEIGHT = 800;
private static int STROKESIZE = 7;

private BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

public Color currentColor;

public static boolean eraser = false;

private int xX1, yY1;

public DrawBoard(){  

   Graphics2D g2d = bImage.createGraphics();
   g2d.dispose();

    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.setSize(1024,800); //w, h
    setPreferredSize(size);
    //status =  new JLabel("default");
    //add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);  


     imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bImage)) {
     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        paintInLabel(g);
     }
   };
     imgLabel.setOpaque(false);
     setOpaque(false);
      add(imgLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

private void paintInLabel(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g2d.setColor(getColor()); // this colour is when mouse is pressed
  g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKESIZE));
  if (points.size() < 2) {
     return;
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
     int x1 = points.get(i - 1).x;
     int y1 = points.get(i - 1).y;
     int x2 = points.get(i).x;
     int y2 = points.get(i).y;
     g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  }
 }


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){  
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){  
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){   
}

// Where the drawing happens
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //status.setText("you pressed down the mouse");
    xX1 = e.getX();
    yY1 = e.getY();


        points.add(e.getPoint());
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  //status.setText("you draged the mouse");
        points.add(e.getPoint());
        imgLabel.repaint();

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //status.setText("you release the mouse click");
    Graphics2D g2d = bImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(getColor()); // this is the final colour
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKESIZE));


     if (points.size() >= 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i < points.size(); i++) {
           int x1 = points.get(i - 1).x;
           int y1 = points.get(i - 1).y;
           int x2 = points.get(i).x;
           int y2 = points.get(i).y;
           g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
     }
     g2d.dispose();

     points.clear();
     imgLabel.repaint();

}
// End of where the drawing happens

public void clearDrawBoard() {

}

private Color getColor() {

    return ColourToolbar.selectedColor;
}

private void setColor(Color col){

    this.currentColor = col;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

}
```

Comment: Did you already try `g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0))` and then 'fillRect'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [set a custom Composite for your Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite%28java.awt.Composite%29), specifically [AlphaComposite.Clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html#Clear) before drawing the rectangle. Don't forget to reset the composite to the default (SRC_OVER) when you are done, because the same Graphics object will be reused to paint other components.

Comment: This definitely did the job, I lost hope since I read last night that you couldn't overwrite with alpha pixels, but now it works like a charm! Thanks so much and hopefully people looking for this will get help from this answer!

Comment: The answer could do with some example code, from here it isn't clear how to reset to SRC_OVER, as AlphaComposite.Clear and SRC_OVER are different types. You in fact want to set it back to AlphaComposite.SrcOver.